# How to add an log file into Keycloak provider jar

Tags: jboss, keycloak, log4j2

I have created a provider jar for catching event in Keycloak. I would like to write logs using log4j2.xml.
I added log4j2.xml file under Resource/META-INF folder. After I deployed the jar in Keycloak I'm getting an error saying "ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found." Attaching my project structure

[image]

Do I need to specify log4j2.xml somewhere else?

Comment: Why do you want to use log4j2 instead of existing logging subsystem in Keycloak?

Comment: Basically what I want is, I need to send the keycloak logs to Graylog server.I would like to add an GELF appender in log4j2. This will send the keycloak logs to Graylog server.